# Manage NugetPackage for Solution can't find any online packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Somehow, the "**Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**" Dialog doesn't show any online packages anymore (no items found.):

[image]

But the "**Manage NuGet Packages...**" dialog at the project level **works fine**.

I already tryed to start Visual Studio (2013 Update 4) with the /Log Parameter but cannot find any errors in the ActivityLog.xml.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe one of your `repositories.config` files is corrupted or read-only. I suggest that you backup everything, then delete `repositories.config` one by one until the problem is resolved. Once you know which file to blame, you can take a closer look to figure what happened to it.

Comment: Somehow it works without any changes. However, your answer would also help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me:

Delete:

```
%AppData%\NuGet\Nuget.config
```

Restart Visual Studio

Comment: Worked for me too! :)

Answer (score 3):

The package source is missing from your nuget manager.

Without experimenting too much I see two ways to solve it. (as of vs17/2021)

1. Do as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39274085/521554) above (remove `nuget.config` and restart visual studio)
2. Add nuget as source through menu:Tool->Options->NugetPackageManger->PackageSources and add [name='nuget'], [source='https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'] (image below)

---

For more clarity: I did as 1) and my `nuget.config` went from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

so a third option would be to hack the `nuget.config` manually, and restart visual studio.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with Nuget 4.3.1 and I had to delete my NuGet.config file in %AppData%\NuGet\

Close Visual Studio 2015, delete the NuGet.config file in %AppData%\NuGet\ and restart Visual Studio.

A new NuGet.Config file is generated and I was able to get back to work.

If you're in doubt, take a copy of the file first..  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

VS 2017: In my solution, I had a .nuget folder (a solution artifact, not necessarily a file folder) with a .config file which file was missing.  I deleted that folder and restarted visual studio.  After this things worked.